# Почему в sidebar у Sublime Text 3 не видны CSS файлы?

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Прошу совета.
Почему в sidebar у Sublime Text 3 не видны CSS файлы? 
Спасибо.

Comment: Вы папку с проектом в Sublime перетягиваете и папки css не видно или как?

Comment: Спасибо, все решилось. Смотрите ниже, я написал.

Comment: @oldeev, отметьте ответ как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом), чтобы помочь людям с похожим на ваш вопросом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Sublime Text фильтрация файлов может быть включена глобально и на уровне проекта.

- настройки проекта: меню `Project -> Edit Project`
- глобальные пользовательские настройки: `Preferences -> Settings - User`
- глобальные стандартные настройки: `Preferences -> Settings - Default` *(в ST3 не редактируются)*

Параметр, отвечающий за исключение файлов называется `file_exclude_patterns`

Отключение CSS файлов может выглядеть как-то так: `"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.css"]`
Если такое есть, надо удалить оттуда `"*.css"`

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Я проект не создавал, открыл как папку. Ваш ответ натолкнул на мысль: а где-то есть подобная настройка, в Preferences, м.б., для общего профиля?
Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Все, нашел! В Preferences - User  file_exclude_patterns. Vive la xEdelweiss!

Comment: :) Да, я тоже вспомнил об этом месте. Сейчас обновлю ответ.